# How can I add new drawer items? but I get exception

Tags: flutter

When I add much more `driwerItem`, I get an exception. How can I fix this?

https://github.com/flutter-tuts/drawer_demo

Comment: what exception did you get ?

Comment: https://pastiebin.com/5b4f6d75a0c10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can build a drawer like this :

```
     drawer: new Drawer(

        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text("First"),
              onTap: (){ print("firs"); },
            ),
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text("Second"),
              onTap: (){ print("Second"); },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add new drawer items as

```
final drawerItems = [
new DrawerItem("Fragment 1", Icons.rss_feed),
new DrawerItem("Fragment 2", Icons.local_pizza),
new DrawerItem("Fragment 3", Icons.info),
new DrawerItem("Fragment 4", Icons.info)
];
```

and add new fragment at

```
 _getDrawerItemWidget(int pos) {
switch (pos) {
  case 0:
    return new FirstFragment();
  case 1:
    return new SecondFragment();
  case 2:
    return new ThirdFragment();
  case 2:
    return new FourthFragment();

  default:
    return new Text("Error");
}
```

}

Comment: Add your drawer inside listview.
    drawer: new Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 90.0,
                  color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
                  child: new FlutterLogo(size: 55.0,),
                ),
                new Column(children: drawerOptions)
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),